# Factorization in the Wiener algebra on the unit disc.

Tags: banach-algebras, cv.complex-variables, factorization, fa.functional-analysis

Consider the Banach algebra $W^+=\ell^1(\mathbb{Z}^+)$, viewed upon as the analytic functions $f$ on the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ such that $$\|f\|=\sum_{k\ge0}|a_k|<\infty$$ where
$$f(z)=\sum a_kz^k$$
is the Taylor expansion of $f$. Clearly, $W^+\subset H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$. Now, it is well known that $H^\infty$ admits inner-outer factorization. Is there some similar factorization theorem for $W^+$?

Comment: Very interesting question, but could you possibly write $W_+$ instead of $A$, since $A$ usually means the disc algebra instead, and it's destroying my brain every time I see $A$ here?

It looks very difficult; do you know what happens for the disc algebra? I don't know, but for many properties the Wiener and disc algebra are much "closer" and more similar to each other than they are to $H^\infty$, so it could be relevant.

Do you know anything about Blaschke products in the Wiener algebra? I don't, but it could be another good thing to look at; I haven't managed to find very much yet.

Comment: @Zen Harper: I hope this is better. I have no solution, we would have to use a different technique in order to do something (in $W^+$ or in $A(\mathbb{D})$).

Comment: The analytic Wiener algebra and the disc algebra might be closer in spirit than either is to $H^\infty$, but they are very different from each other. For instance, take the Blaschke product $b(z)$ with one simple zero at $a$; then generically the norm of $b^n$ inside $W_+$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$ if I recall correctly (Katznelson?). Have you tried looking at some of the papers Jean Esterle cowrote concerning zero sets in $W_+$?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Yes, the disc algebra might be more promising in the sense it is more similar to $H^\infty$. I do not know about Esterle's work in $W^+$ - do you have a ref. where I can start? 

Comment: If you have MathSciNet access: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1273955 But it is difficult to know what to suggest without a more precise notion of "some similar factorization theorem". What do you hope to be true, and what do you know to be false?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: No, I can not MathSciNet any more. Having a factorization theorem I would hope to get more info on how the functions without zeros look like. My main interest is to get a better understand of the invisible spectrum (see http://aif.cedram.org/item?id=AIF_1999__49_6_1925_0).


Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no factorization in Wiener algebra, it is easy to construct a counterexample.

Namely, if $B$ is a Blaschke factor with zeroes $z_n$, $z_n\to 1$ (of course $\sum(1-|z_n|) <\infty$) and $g= (z-1)^2$ then 
$
f= Bg$ has $C^1$ boundary values, and so is in the Wiener algebra.

On the other hand, $B$ is an inner part of $f$ (in $H^\infty$), and it is not in $W$, because it is not even continuous at $1$.

On the other hand, if $f(z)\ne 0$ for all $z:|z|=1$, then $f$ has only finitely many zeroes in the unit disc, so the factorization is trivial: the inner part is a finite Blaschke product.